# Trimming one polyline against another that intersects using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, line, editing, arcgis-9.2

Instructions for splitting a polygon at an intersecting line work fine in ArcMap 9.2. I have Open Data from Ordnance Survey and want to trim every line and polygon at a nearby North-South National Grid line. However instructions for trimming polylines against the same grid line simply do not work, no error messages, nothing. It says to use Line Intersection Tool on the Advanced Editing toolbar.

What do you put in as the Current Task Target layer?

The help only says: Click the Line Intersection Tool, then the first feature to intersect, then the second. Then, you get a diagonal line which rotates about the intersection in question, but no clue as to what it means.

When you see this, what is the next step?

The instructions say choose which 'intersection solution' you want. I want to trim on of the lines against the other!

Do I left click, right click??

I am using ArcMap 9.2.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: You're using 9.2?  Really? We're talking some seriously ancient software (released in 2006, it's nearly old enough to have a "Please be patient, Student Driver" magnet on the media kit).

Comment: Well thanks for that, very helpful. 9.2 is otherwise fine for me.